# Unique factorisation domains

Tags: number-theory

The question is:

Let $\alpha$ be a non-zero non-unit element of $\mathbb{Z} [i]$. Using the fact that $\mathbb{Z} [i]$ is a unique factorisation domain, describe how to determine all the $\beta \in \mathbb{Z} [i]$ with $N(\beta)=N(\alpha)$.

My thoughts are that $\alpha$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ so $\alpha$ is not a unit and $N(\alpha)\neq 1$. As a result $N(\beta)\neq 1$ so $\beta$ is not a unit which means $\beta$ is irreducible. Since $N(\beta)=N(\alpha)$ then $\beta$ is an associate of $\alpha$. However I'm not really sure how to continue or how I'm supposed to use that $\mathbb{Z} [i]$ is a UFD. Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you conclude that $\beta$ and $\alpha$ should be associate when $N(\beta) = N(\alpha)$? Take $\beta = 5i$ and $\alpha = 3+4i$. Are they associates?

Comment: Oh I see. I didn't realise that the reversal of if $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are associate then $N(\alpha)$ is associate to $N(\beta)$ isn't true.

Comment: If $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are associate then $\alpha \mid \beta$ and $\beta \mid \alpha$ so that $\alpha = u_1\beta$ and $\beta = u_2\alpha$. Then you have that $\alpha = u_1u_2\alpha$ which implies that $u_1u_2 = 1$, hence $u_1$ and $u_2$ are units. Then if you take the norm and use the multiplicativity, $N(\alpha) = N(u_1\beta) = N(u_1)N(\beta) = N(\beta)$ since the norm of a unit is $1$. So you know at least that all associates of $\alpha$ have norm equal to the norm of $\alpha.$ But, as shown above, there are more cases to look at

Comment: Also, "not a unit" does not imply "irreducible". The element $13$ is not a unit, but $13 = (3 + 2i)(3-2i)$.